# c# 8x8 grid and finding matching symbols adjacent

Tags: c#, .net, grid, match

Okay say you have a grid like this

```
xxxxSxxx
xxxxSSxx
xxxSSSxx
xxSSxSSx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
```

Where the x are non matching adjacent symbols and the S are matching ones
How would one go through to find the matching ones? to know they are matching in a good way?
i was thinking of going from top-left to top-bottom comparing right and bottom adjacent but that becomes a problem when it goes down and then left matching. Any guidance is very much appriciated to add to it. There can be more than one cluster and only if there are a certain amount it counts like 5+ adajcent otherwise ignore

Comment: How is this grid saved? Is it a string / array / 2d array?

Comment: @ToTheMax its a 2d array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there's only one cluster of `s` and the grid is stored in 2D matrix.

You can create a new 2D matrix and then go over each element in the original grid. If it is equal to at least one of the adjacent elements (be careful when comparing elements on the edges of the grid so you won't go outside of the grid) then mark its place (its `x` and `y`) as 1 in the new matrix. If it is not equal to any of the adjacent elements then mark its position in the new matrix with 0.

When you are done. The places where you have 1s in the new matrix are the places where you have `s` in the old matrix.

Edit: solution to the new problem in the comment.

Create a  new 2D grid. Go over the old one and from each cell that you haven't touched (isn't visited) start a BFS search from it. Expand the BFS only into cells that have the same symbol as the cell you started this BFS search from. When you visit a cell mark its place in the new matrix with the number of which BFS search it is. For example if this is your third BFS search. Mark the place of each element you visited in the new matrix with the number of which BFS search this is.

When you start each BFS search keep a count of how many elements you have visited until now. When they cross the threshold you have. Put the number of the BFS in an array or a victor. That way when you are done. You go to this vector each number in it is a cluster of symbol that are above the threshold you have.

For example you see 3 in your vector and you want to know the places of the cluster number 3 you can go to the new 2D grid look for the first element with the number 3 and start a BFS search from it to know where it's friends are.

Comment: This sounds good. If for say a certain amount is needed to be counted as enough like 4 adjacent how would you do to eliminate The ones that has for example 3

Comment: Do you know what BFS or DFS is? If you do, I can explain a solution

Comment: See my edit on my solution. It was too big to write in a comment.